# Install slick carousel in VueJS project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, carousel, vue-cli

I am trying to use the slick carousel in my vue project. I am following this steps:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slick

But i get always this message:

> npm WARN slick-carousel@1.8.1 requires a peer of jquery@>=1.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN vue-slick@1.1.13 requires a peer of jquery@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

And this is my package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17.1",
        "element-ui": "^2.4.3",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "pug-runtime": "^2.0.3",
        "reset-css": "^2.2.1",
        "sass-resources-loader": "^1.3.3",
        "vue": "^2.5.2",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
        "vue-slick": "^1.1.13",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^21.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "coffee-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "coffee-script": "~1.6.3",
    "coffeescript": "^2.1.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jest": "^22.0.4",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^0.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "pug-module": "^1.1.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "sass-variable-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-jest": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  }
```

Also I have removed the node_modules folder and then I have installed but I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following command to install the required dependecies:

```
npm install jquery@>=1.8.0 --save-dev
```